# Pin content view in UIScrollView to its bottom rather than its top edge

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

A `UIScrollView` pins its content view by default to its top edge, i.e. when you add some content to a scroll view with a vertical scrolling axis and the content's total height is smaller than the height of the whole scroll view, the content is displayed at the top of the scroll view.

**Is there a way to change this behavior** and make the scroll view pin its content view to its bottom?

(In other words: I would like the content to "grow from the bottom".)

---

[image: Example layouts]

---

Comment: Are you using a plain UIScrollView or a UITableView? If you're using a plain scroll view how are you currently adding and positioning your subviews?

Comment: Do you want a particular view in the scroll view to be pinned at the bottom while other content scrolls beneath it?

Comment: It’s a general UIScrollView, not specific to table views or anything. I’m adding a view to the scroll view as a subview and use layout constraints to pin it to its super view bounds.

Comment: I want the content view and everything inside the scroll view to scroll normally, no fixed position of the view.

Answer (score 1):

The usual workaround is to flip the scroll view, then flip the content view.

e.g.

```
        scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

I'd really like to know a cleaner solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to add a view to the scrollview in a certain position

this is simple example code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var views: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        views = UIView.init()
        scrollView = UIScrollView.init()


        scrollView.addSubview(views)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        addViewToBottomScroll()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1300)
        scrollView.frame = self.view.frame
        scrollView.contentSize = views.frame.size
    }

    func addViewToScrollView() {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40))
        label.text = "ScrollView"
        label.textAlignment = .center

        views.addSubview(label)

        let bottomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 15.0, y: 950.0, width: self.view.frame.width - 30, height: 300))
        bottomView.backgroundColor = .yellow

        views.addSubview(bottomView)
    }
}
```

[image]

hopefully answer your question

Comment: No, that is not an answer to my question. Your `views` which you set to 1300 points in height _is_ the scroll view's content view. I want to pin that content view to the bottom (when its less tall than the scroll view), not any of its subviews.